# Word starter always opens files even when Word 2010 is installed

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have Word starter installed on my computer. It works fine and opens and edits files.

I just installed a full version of Word 2010.  It works fine.

However, when I double-click on a `.docx` file, it is opened in Word Starter.

How do I get the computer to open `.docx` file in Word 2010? Why did Word 2010 not upgrade or remove Word Starter?

Answer (score 2):

Yes

Right Click the File, Select Open With Option.
If Open With is not there try holding shift while right clicking.

After Open With is visible Select Word 2010 or browse to it if there it not in the list.
Do also check Select Default Program or Always Open With option.

From now on you are Good to go!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Right click the file, select *Properties*. When the properties window pops up, look for the section that says *Opens With* just below the top. There will be a button to the right that says *Change*. When you click that button, a dialog will appear that will have a list of recommended programs and Word 2010 should be on the list. If it is not, you can use the browse button to look for it. Once you hit *OK* at this window it will change it so that explorer opens that file type in Word 2010 instead of Word Starter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be a compatibility conflict between the two software programs.

To fix this just:

`Start Menu` > `Default Programs` > `Associate a file type or protocol with a program`

Look for `docx` (You can simple just type in .docx and it should select it in the list.

Then click `Change Program` on the top right. And select Microsoft Word. If Microsoft Word is not in the list then the path should be something like: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE`

You can also just right click the file and go to `Properties`, then change the default program from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into your control panel change view to large or small icon by 'view' in top right corner. Go into default programs click associate file type or protocol with a specific program. Look at the program icon in column one you will need to know this to know what program to select. Whenever it lists under the third list current default programs 'Microsoft Application Virtualization launcher' sometimes includes DDE in the launcher statement double click on the words Microsoft Application Virtualization launcher. you then get up a box that says 'open with' choose program you want to open this file with. Click on the blue down arrow on right which is opposite the words other program. You will then see a list with icons of the programs you normally use. If the icon in column one was a word one just click on Microsoft word and hey presto it will change the third column to 'Microsoft Word' There are several Microsoft Application Virtualization launcher to change with each program in word, and excel and picture they was just one I did not change because it said an unknown application

Your programs will now open in the way they did before you set up Starter Office 2010.

I hope this helps